# is this possible in css to place content like this in a predictable way

Tags: css

I asked somethign similar and got a great answer. I have this jsbin http://jsbin.com/nuwagibayo/1/edit?html,css,output and now we have:

[image]

with the 12.50 being repositioned a bit awkwardly but not terribly. Now we'd like to move the 12.50 into the same location in the jt-row above like this:

[image]

It's possible to add a wrapper to both of them but not really to reposition the price. Is is possible with the current html to position this in CSS? I can't really use the jt-container as a head but might be able to bring a separate like jt-item-container or some other structure.

Comment: You can give position:relative to .jt-container than .jt-row

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is just slide it up, then you can just change your positioning:

```
.jt-item-price{
    top: -80px;
}
```

---

### [Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yoqiqibuku/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: thx, yeah, ideally that top piece could be any height so is there some way of saying like 'make it 10 pixels off the top of the previous jt-row'; I'm strongly thinking this is a jQuery sol'n

Comment: @timpone Without restructuring your table, that is the best solution you can get with CSS.

Comment: CSS is designed with a forward-mindset. It is very easy to move and target elements that appear *after* your current element, but not so easy to do the same to elements *before* your current element. For instance, if you wanted to do the same thing, but slide it down to the top of the next row, all you'd need is `top: 100%` and BAM!